How to use Consolas and Helvetica in Overleaf?
I would like to be able to use both Helvetica and Consolas in an Overleaf document.
In specific, I want the listing for Matlab in this script to be in Consolas, and I specifically want it in Consolas, not the replacement Inconsolata.
Is this possible? I am confused with regards to selecting xelatex, luatex, pdflatex.
Here is the link the editable Overleaf document.
Here is the read only link, which does not require signin in.

please provide a minimal working example here. questions shouldn't rely on external links in order to ensure they remain useful to future readers. you can use any font you like with xetex or luatex, so if you have a copy of the fonts and the licence allows you to upload it to overleaf, you can use it provided it is opentype (or the opentype flavour of truetype). I'm assuming you don't need pdftex. if not, forget that. luatex is probably your best option.

I have uploaded the Helvetica.ttc into your project folder and it works well under xelatex and lualatex.
Code Changes
The font configuration under xelatex and lualatex should be something like
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont{Helvetica.ttc}[UprightFeatures= {FontIndex=0} ,
  BoldFeatures= {FontIndex=1} ,
  ItalicFeatures= {FontIndex=2} ,
  BoldItalicFeatures = {FontIndex=3} ,]
\setmonofont{Consolas.ttf}

and the value of key basicstyle is changed to \ttfamily.
